# Discord bot can't speak on Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, discord.js, voice

I have a Discord bot which was deployed to Heroku. Everything work when i run my bot on PC, but on Heroku it can't speak in the voice channel and I have no idea whats went wrong with it.

Earlier i thought that the problem was with `node-opus`. I've decided to install `opusscript` instead this, but I've received the same result and bot still not working. I pasted a piece of code from my package.json file below.

````
"dependencies": {
    "discord.js": "^11.5.1",
    "ffmpeg-binaries": "^4.0.0",
    "google-tts-api": "^0.0.4",
    "opusscript": "0.0.6",
    "simple-youtube-api": "^5.2.0",
    "sqlite3": "^4.0.9",
    "ytdl-core": "^0.29.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node bot",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  }```
````

Answer (score 0):

you have to add:

- ffmpeg
- node_opus (or anything related to opus)

as buildpacks, for more info go [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks)

Comment: Still not work and nothing was changed. Do you have any other ideas to fix this?

Comment: And after starting playing i received this error `(node:4) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.`